# How to remove a particular line drawn in canvas

Tags: android, darwin

I am using the code

```
myCanvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

I use it to remove the line if it is not at the exact position.

But it clear all the lines drawn in canvas.

So, how can I remove a particular line from it

Comment: Have you tried with `invalidate();` ?

Comment: Do you want `undo-redo` features or just want to remove some random line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clip the canvas before drawing:
clipRect(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) You should make the rect area 1px wide.

Second, drawColor to clear the clipped area. drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);

Comment: yes I used dawaLine in my code but my main problem is to remove a particular line from the canvas